# Я новичков в питоне, решил сдеалть камень-ножницы-бумага:

Tags: python

```
   while True:
   print(Fore.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX + f'Привет, это камень-ножницы-бумага')
   choice = input('Камень? Ножницы? Или бумага?: ')
   list = ['камень', 'ножницы', 'бумага']
   computere_choice = random.choice(list)

   'камень' < 'бумага' , 'ножницы' < 'камень', 'бумага' < 'ножницы'
   if choice > computere_choice:
       print( Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + "Вы выиграли, компьютер выбрал " + computere_choice)
   elif choice == computere_choice:
       print( Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + 'Ничья')
   elif choice < computere_choice:
       print(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + "Вы проиграли, компьютер выбрал " + computere_choice)

else:
   print('')
```

P.S: Выдает вот это:

```
Привет, это камень-ножницы-бумага
Камень? Ножницы? Или бумага?: бумага
Ничья
Привет, это камень-ножницы-бумага
Камень? Ножницы? Или бумага?: ножницы
Ничья
Привет, это камень-ножницы-бумага
Камень? Ножницы? Или бумага?: камень
Вы выиграли, компьютер выбрал бумага
```

Comment: и в чём конкретно вам помочь то?

Comment: Мне выдает если я выбрал камень что я победил а компьютер выбрал бумагу. Как так, если в условиях все указано?

Comment: ваша ошибка что вы сравниваете строки - так делать нельзя

Comment: фактически, вы сравниваете не приоритетный выбор, а просто информацию о строке.

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно такое сложное сравнение, достаточно сделать пару условий:

```
import random
print('Привет, это камень-ножницы-бумага')
while True:
    choice = input('Камень? Ножницы? Или бумага?: ')
    computer_choice = random.choice(['камень', 'ножницы', 'бумага'])
    print(f'Вы выбрали {choice}, компьютер выбрал {computer_choice}.')
    if choice.lower()==computer_choice:
        print('Ничья!')

    elif choice.lower() == 'камень':
        if computer_choice=='ножницы':
            print('Вы победили!')
        elif computer_choice == 'бумага':
            print('Победил компьютер!')

    elif choice.lower() == 'ножницы':
        if computer_choice == 'камень':
            print('Победил компьютер!')
        elif computer_choice == 'бумага':
            print('Вы победили!')

    elif choice.lower() == 'бумага':
        if computer_choice == 'камень':
            print('Вы победили!')
        elif computer_choice == 'ножницы':
            print('Победил компьютер!')
    else:
        print('Неправильный выбор!')
    print('------------------------------------')
```